# Wordpress Plugin error. Backup Buddy

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am having a error when using `BackupBuddy` plugin for wordpress. I can not find the error anywhere online.

> Error #82389: A javascript error occured which may prevent the backup
>   from continuing. Check your browser error console for details. This is
>   most often caused by another plugin or theme containing broken
>   javascript. See details below for clues or try temporarily disabling
>   all other plugins.
>
> Details: 'Access is denied. '.
>
> URL: 'http:// (OUR
>   URL)/wp-content/plugins/backupbuddy/js/backupPreform.js?ver=7.2.0.2'.
>
> Line:'22'.

Comment: So did you deactivate all your other plugins?

Comment: Yes, Still has the error.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you the exact fix for the problem, but I can point you in the right direction and seeing that nobody has answered in 1 hour, I hope it helps. The issue is that there are 2 libraries that need to load; one for backupbuddy and one for another plugin or theme(I'm pretty sure its your theme). The library for backupbuddy is not loading and causing the error. Usually one library- like Jquery - can be used by multiple plugins but its not working in this case.

You might already know this, but I'll mention it anyways, if you set WP_DEBUG to true in your wp-config.php file, it might show you the location of where the conflict is happening in the other file. Another thing I would try is removing and re-installing the current theme you are using to ensure that all files are updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share my experience with fixing this problem in case it can be helpful to others. As with the original post, I was attempting to use BackupBuddy (version 8.1 2017) and kept getting this error: Error #82389: A javascript error occurred... jQuery...

Going to the Wordpress "Dashboard", I noticed none of the content fields were displayed. They were frozen in the "Loading..." state, a good indication that my Wordpress files were not working properly.

.

HERE IS WHAT I DID:

o Updated all plugins.

o Backed up files and database using cPanel (on my hosting server).

o Updated Wordpress to the latest version (4.9.1 Dec. 2017).

o Ran BackupBuddy again. This time it worked! Problem solved.

. . .

NOTE: If there is no update to your version of Wordpress, it might help to reinstall that version again. You should first perform a **full backup** of your files and your database using an alternative to BackupBuddy.

#### Full Backup: Using the tools on your hosting server (I use cPanel)

I also suspect in my case the plugins were not the problem, but it didn't hurt. Updating the Wordpress files was probably the most important step. Notice, however, that I did NOT disable any plugins, although that could be an important step for others having this problem with BackupBuddy errors.